# How to use dataframes within a map function in Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

#### Definitions:

- `sampleDF` is sample dataframe that has a list record for look up purposes.
- `sampleDS` is a RDD with list of elements in it.
- `mappingFunction` is to look up the elements of `sampleDS` in `sampleDF` and map them to 1 if they exist in `sampleDF` and to 0 if they don't.

I have a mapping function as follows:

```
def mappingFunction(element):
    # The dataframe lookup!
    lookupResult = sampleDF.filter(sampleDF[0] == element).collect()
    if len(lookupResult) > 0:
        print lookupResult
        return 1
    return 0
```

#### The problem:

Accessing `sampleDF` outside of the mapping function works perfectly fine but as soon as I use it inside the function I get the following error:

```
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:335)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:344)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:252)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

#### What else I tried:

I did try saving a temporary table and using the `sqlContext` select inside the map function and still couldn't get this to work. This is the error I get:

```
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 686, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 542, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

#### What I am asking for:

I have tried to simplify my problem through simple example. Any help on how to use a dataframe **inside** a map function is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible. Spark doesn't support nested operations on distributed data structures (`RDDs`, `DataFrames`, `Datasets`). Even if it did executing large number of jobs wouldn't be a good idea. Given the code you've shown you probably want to convert your RDD to a `DataFrame` and perform `join` wit

```
(rdd.map(x => (x, )).toDF(["element"])
  .join(sampleDF, sampleDF[0] == df[0])
  .groupBy("element")
  .agg(count("element") > 0))
```

On a side note printing inside `map` is completely useless not mention it add additional IO overhead.

Comment: Thanks for that. I simplified the thing that I am trying to do. Based on a few conditions, the data in the RDD has to be mapped into different things. What about a python in memory dict can I use that? As in load the data in the DataFrame into a python dict instead and use that in the map function.

Comment: Yes you can. You can use broadcast variables as well. You simply cannot use distributed data structure.